# Redefinition error after updating to 0.39.0

Tags: ios, cocoapods, sdwebimage, redefinition

I updated **Cocoapods to version 0.39.0** and I now I get a lot of redefinition errors in ***SDWebImageDownloader.h***
For the records this are the pods I'm using:

```
Using AFNetworking (1.3.4)
Using ChameleonFramework (2.0.4)
Using Crashlytics (3.4.0)
Using DZNEmptyDataSet (1.7.2)
Using ECSlidingViewController (2.0.3)
Using Fabric (1.6.0)
Using FontAwesomeKit (2.2.0)
Using GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
Using Heap (2.2.1)
Using ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer (0.6.1)
Using RKValueTransformers (1.1.2)
Using RMMapper (1.1.5)
Using RestKit (0.25.0)
Using SDWebImage (3.7.3)
Using SOCKit (1.1)
Using SVProgressHUD (1.1.3)
Using SwipeView (1.3.2)
Using TLYShyNavBar (0.9.8)
Using TTTAttributedLabel (1.13.4)
Using TransitionKit (2.1.1)
Using UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage (1.2)
Using iRate (1.11.4)
```

Any idea about a possible fix?

Comment: Getting this problem as well, using Cocoapods _1.0.0.beta.2_

How did you solve it?

Comment: in my specific case I removed I removed SDWebImage and it compiled. Not sure why